# JBOSS EAP6.2 to IBM MQ Integration

Tags: jboss7.x, ibm-mq, jboss-eap-6

We are planning to migrate our applications from WebSphere to JBOSS EAP6.2, As part of that I am looking to integrate WMQ7.5.2 to JBOSS EAP in domain mode, I have searched over the JBOSS Forums and made the necessary changes in my domain.xml , but my doubt is below

I have 2 Nodes/Unix Servers for JBOSS EAP

NODE 1  has the below

1) JBOSS EAP Installed and running in domain mode ( Master) , modified domain.xml , host.xml

2) Server 1 - Part of Server Group

3) QMGR A

NODE 2 has the below

1) JBOSS EAP Installed and running in Slave Mode , modifed host.xml

2) Server 2 - Part of the same Server Group as server 1

3) QMGR B

I have integrated IBM WMQ by changing my parameters in domain.xml

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:resource-adapters:1.1">
        <resource-adapters>
            <resource-adapter id="wmq.jmsra.rar">
                <archive>
                    wmq.jmsra.rar
                </archive>
                <transaction-support>NoTransaction</transaction-support>
                <config-property name="logWriterEnabled">
                    true
                </config-property>
                <config-property name="traceEnabled">
                    true
                </config-property>
                <config-property name="traceLevel">
                    3
                </config-property>
                <config-property name="connectionConcurrency">
                    5
                </config-property>
                <config-property name="maxConnections">
                    15
                </config-property>
                <connection-definitions>
                    <connection-definition class-name="com.ibm.mq.connector.outbound.ManagedConnectionFactoryImpl jndi-name="java:jboss/XXXPrimaryQCF" enabled="true" use-java-context="true" pool-name="APTPPrimaryQCF">
                   <config-property name="port">
                          1420
                   </config-property>
                   <config-property name="hostName">
                     XX.XX.XX.XX1
                   </config-property>
                   <config-property name="channel">
                        SYSTEM.DEF.SVRCONN
                   </config-property>
                   <config-property name="transportType">
                        CLIENT
                    </config-property>
                    <config-property name="queueManager">
                      XXXXXX1
                    </config-property>
                 </connection-definition>

                 <connection-definition class-name="com.ibm.mq.connector.outbound.ManagedConnectionFactoryImpl jndi-name="java:jboss/XXXSecondaryQCF" enabled="true" use-java-context="true" pool-name="APTPSecondaryQCF">
                   <config-property name="port">
                          1420
                   </config-property>
                   <config-property name="hostName">
                     XX.XX.XX.XX2
                   </config-property>
                   <config-property name="channel">
                        SYSTEM.DEF.SVRCONN
                   </config-property>
                   <config-property name="transportType">
                        CLIENT
                    </config-property>
                    <config-property name="queueManager">
                      XXXXXX2
                    </config-property>
                 </connection-definition>
                 <admin-objects>                     
                 <admin-object class-name="com.ibm.mq.connector.outbound.MQQueueProxy" jndi-name="java:jboss/jms/XXXWriterPrimaryQueue" pool-name="OdsWriterQueue">
                    <config-property name="baseQueueManagerName">
                            XXXXXX1
                    </config-property>
                    <config-property name="baseQueueName">
                            XX.XQ.QA
                    </config-property>
                 </admin-object>
                 <admin-object class-name="com.ibm.mq.connector.outbound.MQQueueProxy" jndi-name="java:jboss/jms/XXXWriterSecondaryQueue" pool-name="OdsWriterQueue">
                    <config-property name="baseQueueManagerName">
                            XXXXXX2
                    </config-property>
                    <config-property name="baseQueueName">
                            XX.XQ.QB
                    </config-property>
                 </admin-object>

                 <admin-object class-name="com.ibm.mq.connector.outbound.MQQueueProxy" jndi-name="java:jboss/jms/XXXXWriterPrimaryQueue" pool-name="OdsWriterQueue">
                    <config-property name="baseQueueManagerName">
                           XXXXXX1
                    </config-property>
                    <config-property name="baseQueueName">
                            XX.XQ.QA
                    </config-property>
                 </admin-object>
              </admin-objects>
            </resource-adapter>
        </resource-adapters>
    </subsystem>


 <mdb>
       <resource-adapter-ref resource-adapter-name="wmq.jmsra.rar"/>
       <bean-instance-pool-ref pool-name="mdb-strict-max-pool"/>
 </mdb>


 <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:ee:1.1">
 <spec-descriptor-property-replacement>true</spec-descriptor-property-replacement>
 <jboss-descriptor-property-replacement>true</jboss-descriptor-property-replacement>
</subsystem>
```

In our WebSphere enviroment  we have created JMS resources at Node Scope , So Server 1 only communicated to QMGR A and Server 2 only Communicated to QMGR B , but I am not sure how to configure this scope here in JBOSS so that Server 1 on Node 1 will only have reference QMGR1 and Server 2 on Node 2 will have reference to QMGR2 , Can some please guide me

Comment: Small correction is my questions it is as below NODE 2 has the below

1) JBOSS EAP Installed and running in Slave Mode , modifed host.xml

2) Server 2 - Part of the same Server Group as server 1

3) QMGR B

Comment: I have edited your question text to include the correction you above comment applies.

Comment: Based on the description of the issue I think this is a JBOSS configuration issue rather than a MQ-related configuration.  With a single server have you achieve JBOSS-MQ connectivity?

Comment: Yes with a single jboss eap instance running on a stand alone mode i can achieve jboss-mq connectivity

Answer (score 0):

Based on what I can see of the configuration:

Both the hostName and queueManager properties allow expressions,
which means you can define them as **${hostName}** and **${queueManager}** in your profile,
and define **system properties** hostName and queueManager at server-config level, so that at server startup, the expressions are replaced with the specific value for the concerned server-config.
Principle can be applied to other variables as long as they allow for expression, which you can check in CLI with the :read-resource-description() command, you're looking for the "expressions-allowed" information, and value set to true.

Some info regarding expressions: [Expressions - JBoss AS 7.1 - Project Documentation Editor](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/Expressions)

Let me know if this information is clear enough, I can update with some examples if needed.

*Finally a small warning, are you setting your configuration only for outbound (generating messages)?
Because if you are also configuring listeners through this config, you'll end up with errors.*

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hello Oliver, Application logic is as such that it reads records from the file and converts each record into a message and writes into a queue , then internally another asynchronous thread consumes the messages from the Queue using MDB/Listener and sends them to a backend system

Comment: Ok, thanks for the additional context. the warning was related to configuration of consumers. As you have seen, the classes used in the configuration are for outbound messages. the inbound (AFAIK) cannot be configured in JBoss, but need to be configured in a separate xml.

Comment: Let me know if the proposed solution suits your needs, and/or if you need additional information

Comment: For the Inbound we have changed the internal logic now , we are using camel to read the messages from the queue , i will try you changes today and see if it works in my case.